# Property 'Price' does not exist on type 'Observable<wishlist[]> ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am trying to display my initial wishlist state that has a name and price property. I get a " Property 'Price' does not exist on type 'Observable<wishlist[]>" error but Price does exist on the wishlist interface and in the reducer.

I am later going to add a product to the wishlist from my list of products but I want to get the inital state working first.

Maybe I am displaying it wrong in the html? using the for loop incorrectly. I am not sure.

Any help is appreciated.

heres wishlist interface

```
export interface wishlist{
    name: string; 
    Price: string; 

}
```

actions

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store'
import { wishlist } from 'model/wishlist.model'

export const ADD_WISHLIST   = '[WISHLIST] Add'
export const REMOVE_WISHLIST   = '[WISHLIST] Remove'


export class  AddWishlist implements Action{

    readonly type = ADD_WISHLIST


    //creating a class for each of the actions
    constructor(public payload: wishlist) {}
}

export class  RemoveWishlist implements Action{

    readonly type = REMOVE_WISHLIST


    //creating a class for each of the actions
    constructor(public payload: number) {}
}

export type Actions = AddWishlist | RemoveWishlist
```

reducer

```
import { Action, ActionsSubject } from '@ngrx/store'
import { wishlist } from 'model/wishlist.model'
//import { n } from 'node:inspector'
import * as WishlistActions from 'src/app/actions/wishlist.actions'

const initialState: wishlist ={
    name: 'insital wishlist',
    Price: '400'
}

export function wishlistreducer(state : wishlist[] = [initialState], action: WishlistActions.Actions){


    switch(action.type){
        case WishlistActions.ADD_WISHLIST: 
        return [...state, action.payload]; 

        default: 
        return state; 
    }
}
```

app state

```
import { wishlist } from 'model/wishlist.model';

export interface AppState{
    readonly WishList: wishlist[];
}`
```

wishlist html(this is called cart but im using it as a wishlist)

```
<div class="right">

    <h3>Wishlist</h3>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor ="let wishlist of wishlists | async"></li>
        <a>{{ wishlists.Price }}</a>
    </ul>


</div>
```

wishlist component.ts (its called cart dont mind that)

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { wishlist } from 'model/wishlist.model';
import { AppState } from 'src/app/app.state';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {


wishlists: Observable<wishlist[]>; 


  constructor( private store: Store<AppState>) {

    this.wishlists = store.select('WishList')


   }

  ngOnInit(): void {

 
  }
}
```

Comment: You have messed up your binding for `wishlist.Price` you are referencing the observable `wishlists`. Just remove the "s" from the end and it should work `<a>{{ wishlist.Price }}</a>`

Comment: @Sam thanks but it now just tells me "Property 'wishlist' does not exist on type 'CartComponent'. Did you mean 'wishlists'?" but "wishlist" does not need to exist in the component only wishlists I thought? this is where I am a bit lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment, you have used the loop incorrectly. The *ngFor loop is unpackaging your array and assigning each value (iteration) to the variable "wishlist". As such you need to use this variable when accessing the property Price. Currently you are trying to access the property `Price` on the observable that is returned from your store.

```
 <ul>
      <li *ngFor ="let wishlist of wishlists | async">
            <a>{{ wishlist.Price }}</a>
      </li>      
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I tried that and it just tells me that "Property 'wishlist' does not exist on type 'CartComponent'. Did you mean 'wishlists'?" this is why I ended up so confused, maybe its not the binding?

Comment: Ah sorry I misread your code when I scanned over it. The loop must go around your a tags. I will modify my answer to show this @poptart

Comment: Thank you so much!! I cant believe I missed that. Just staring at the thing too long.